Preconditioning conjugate gradient solvers in scipy.optimize.minimize
I'm solving a large unconstrained optimization problem and experimenting with the trust-kyrlov / trust-ncg methods in scipy.optimize.minimize. Unfortunately, these methods can be quite slow when my problem is poorly conditioned. To mitigate this, I am hoping to do the following:
(1) Start with a "warmup" phase where I optimize some fixed number of iterations with LBFGS.
(2) Use the LbfgsInvHessProduct Linear Operator as a pre-conditioner for the trust region method and solve to convergence.
Unfortunately, I do not see a simple way to pass the required preconditioner in step 2 to scipy.optimize.minimize. Is there any way to do this? Or, is there a simple workaround where I could define a custom method with this capability?
Thanks!

I don't see a straightforward way of doing that. You could call scipy.optimize._trustregion._minimize_trust_region with the subproblem argument set to a custom class inheriting from BaseQuadraticSubproblem, like the example here. I am not sure about the specifics of it, though.

I believe there's a way but you need to show a minimum reproducible example.
